# Offset might not be working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1"></div>
</div>
```

In the latest Bootstrap (RC2) and I don't see an empty column between the two.

Question: Is it me?

Comment: @Philip: See my answer below, there's your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfp6x/1/

Try resizing the viewing window in JSFiddle towards the left side, i.e. drag it towards the left and you should see it in effect. Notice that we are using md means medium display so it has to be tested in those conditions.

See this to get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfp6x/2/

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The empty column is there, you don't just see it since it's invisible. But its there, try testing it a couple of times, you should notice the subtle difference when the column offsets towards the right side.;

Comment: I don't know what I did, but it started working properly.  Thanks Ali for showing me that it was working and that it was me.